# Python 2.5 to Python 2.7, script from Batch file won't stop

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file

I have a BAT file that makes something like

```
echo "Start"
python myScript.py <arguments>
del <file>
echo "Finished"
```

When executing it, it never reaches the line where the `del` command is located. I don't know if there is needs of launching the python interpreter with an additional option, but that happens since I upgraded from Python 2.5 to Python 2.7.6.

Comment: what if you try with `call python myScript.py <..>` .Check if python is a bat launcher or an exe file.

Comment: python is the python interpreter executable. I have tried your suggestion but I get the same result.

Comment: If your script is under "run.sh", then run it using `$ bash -x run.sh`.. this will give you more detailed execution log. One curious thing is what is this `del` command ?

Comment: The batch file runs under Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I found that configuring the threading module in my python script for lauching new threads as daemons...

```
threading.Thread.daemon = True
```

My batch file works as it used to!

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!